# validate dropdown elements from a string

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

I just clicked a `dropdown`. Now, how do I check that the expected string is present in the `dropdown`, and if an element is not present, display the message: `"This element is not present"`?

**Code:**

```
driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Work Items')]")).click();

String[] expected = {"Defect", "Task", "Story", "Epic","Design Task"};
```

Comment: is `span` element your selectbox???

Comment: or it is proper `select` element??

Comment: this is the xpath grabbed with a plugin on right click
work items is the menu button that opens the dropdown

Comment: could you provided the HTML of your opened dropdown as well??

Comment: Provide the html code or link to the application if possible

Comment: '
<td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel" colspan="3" data-dojo-attach-point="_td">
<span class="bullet"/>
<a class="itemHref" tabindex="-1" href="#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWelcome">
<span class="MenuItemContent" data-dojo-attach-point="_wrapper">
<img class="dijitIcon dijitMenuItemIcon sprite-image-1" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode" alt="" src="/jazz/web/dojo/resources/blank.gif?etag=ZdS6SgY"/>
<span id="jazz_ui_menu_MenuItem_0_text" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">Welcome to Work Items</span>'the html is huge

Comment: [edit] your question and add it there

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='jazz_ui_menu_MenuItem_30_text']"));
this is the java pulled on one of the dropdown items